# If two vectors are not parallel, can we still compare them i.e. greater than or smaller than?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If vectors $x$ and vector $y$ are a member of $R^n$, and they are not parallel.
Can we say anything about $x>y$ or $x<y$?

I know that they won't be equal because if $x =$ [$x_1, x_2,..., x_n$] and $y =$ [$y_1, y_2,..., y_n$]

$x_i$ will not be equal to $y_i$ for $1<=i<=n$.

Comment: You can compare their magnitudes.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

There is no meaningful order commonly in use for vectors. The best you can do is compare magnitudes $|\mathbf x|$ and $|\mathbf y|$ since these are real numbers and comparison is meaningful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do is compare their magnitudes or perhaps the sum of their entries.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You've answered in the negative but without any reasoned argument to support your answer.  Be wary of posting answers significantly shorter than the Questions that are to be addressed.  Please expand your post to supply reasoning to support a negative resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what order you choose. Actually, we can choose a Lexicographical order to make every pair of elements is comparable:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Orders_on_the_Cartesian_product_of_totally_ordered_sets

If you just consider the product order (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order), not every pair is comparable, but it is a partial order.

Generally speaking, whether $x$ and $y$ are comparable or not depends on the "rule" you define.